# SQL apex oracle error message ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE sessions 
(
    Ses_Start TIME NOT NULL,
    Ses_Finish TIME NOT NULL,
    A_ID NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    Vl_ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    Expense_per_head NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_sessions PRIMARY KEY(A_ID, Vl_ID) 
);
```

I'm trying to create the above table on oracle but I repeatedly get the following error

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00902.php `NUMBER` is probably ok, which leaves `TIME`.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not have a `TIME` data type. You must use `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`, each of which includes both time and date components.